# Alerts (advanced version) doesn't work in sonarqube 4.5.*

Tags: widget, sonarqube, alerts, sonarqube-4.5

I need a help with investigating and fixing Alerts (advanced version) widget in 4.5.*. After upgrading to 4.5.1 it stopped rendering. Upgrading to 4.5.6 did not help.

On dashboard it shows "An error occurred while trying to display the widget "alt_alerts". Please contact the administrator."

Even if I created separated empty Quality Gate for a project, it shows the same error.

In sonar.log:

```
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]  Can not render widget alt_alerts: NilClass can't be coerced into Fixnum
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java:432:in `-'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    compiled-template:48:in `_run_inline_235596400_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    compiled-template:34:in `_run_inline_235596400_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:269:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:162:in `widget_body'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/_widget.html.erb:3:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47_widget46html46erb_locals_object_widget'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:19:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:15:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyRange.java:427:in `each'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:9:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:348:in `_render_with_layout'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:346:in `_render_with_layout'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1252:in `render_for_file'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    jar:file:/usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render_with_benchmark'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1328:in `default_render'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1334:in `perform_action'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_with_filters'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    jar:file:/usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_with_benchmark'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in `send'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:66:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    file:/usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    /usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    file:/usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    file:/usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
2015.11.26 17:39:48 ERROR web[rails]    file:/usr/local/sonarqube-4.5.6/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Comment: After creating a new quality gate and associating it to your project, have you re-run an analysis? If not, you have to do so.

Comment: Yes, I re-run. No affect.

Comment: Are you sure that the empty quality gate is associated to your project? You should see its name in the "Description" widget, along with the quality profile(s) that were used for the analysis.

Comment: It's clear now that Alerts doesn't work if related Quality Gate consists with "Coverage on new code" condition with value "Δ over 30 days" "less than" "0" "80".

Comment: You mean a quality gate that has the same condition as the first one on this page: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/quality_gates/show/4 ? If so, then you have a problem on your side. Have you installed the SCM Activity Plugin? Coverage on new code requires to have SCM information available on your code.

Comment: Exactly.

I have SCM Activity Plugin version 1.8 installed.
I can see coverage on new code on dashboard
I can see next lines in mvn sonar:sonar logs: 
    Collection SCM Change log for the last 30 days
I can see commiter information when I see a java class and click "SCM" button (like http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/SCM+Information+tab)

But when I try to include coverage on new code to the Quality Gate -  it doesn't work

Comment: OK, I read again more carefully your logs, and it turns out that the problem is in a widget provided by the Widget Lab plugin (not by SonarQube itself). Which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: Widget Lab [widgetlab]  1.6

Do you think I can just remove this plugin to get it works?

Comment: Yes, I put my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the widget you are using (which comes from the Widget Lab plugin) has a bug.

You can remove this widget and use the standard "Quality Gate" widget provided out-of-the-box by SonarQube, this will fix your issue.

Comment: Ok, I removed Widget Lab plugin, restarted sonar. And I see no other alerts widget in dashboard configuration :-/

Is it removed in 4.5.*?

Comment: Ah, ok. It's Quality Gate widget.